# Create a RETURN botton for bot

Tags: python-telegram-bot

I'm new to Python-Telegram-Bot

I want to create a bot with return bottom and it means whenever user click the return bottom the bot shows the previous menu to user

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you are new here. A good standard is always show your code in the answer. Actually it's like you are asking for the whole code to someone.

Answer (score 1):

It's not task of python-telegram-bot. You should handle it. For example save last previous(es) state(s) of user (in DB) and after user decide to return, you redirect user to previous state.